# Smart contract for bakers

Tags: baking, smart-contracts

Is it possible to write a Smart contract that would define the relationships between baker and delegator, and if so how would it be done?

It should include the following: 
- delegation duration
- amount of delegation
- service fee
- ROI, Efficiency (optionally)

The idea is to FIX all these parameters. For example:
1) Delegator can not remove their tokens before agreed duration is over. 
2) Delegator can not reduce amount of delegation
3) Baker can not increase the service fee for specified contract
4) Optionally ROI and Efficiency can also be fixed, so baker would guarantee specified ROI and Efficiency or pay from their own pocket should they miss the target

If this is possible, it would be the best Smart contract ever. People would be more selective and baking would become more efficient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack exchange isn't a place to discuss or relay information about opinions or getting software(smart contracts) written.

Comment: really? what stack exchange is for in that case? Maybe the admin of this branch can decide is it off topic or not?

Comment: I do feel this is off topic, but there does seem to be a valid question in there. I've submitted an edit that would bring this more in line with what questions would be, but it could still be closed.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly legitimate and quite reasonably written after Stephen Andrews' editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of demand for such a contract. The problem is currently that Michelson does not expose enough instructions to deal with baking business. So the computation of rewards would be an estimate, not the exact one.

Maybe you could do that with a trusted oracle, the oracle would provide this information to the contract at every cycle. This would have to be done by a trusted third party that does not run a baking service, such as Tzscan, TF, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the idea is very good and the necessity of creating such a contract is confirmed by the community!But now to say exactly when it will be done nobody knows. You still need to communicate with your Baker and monitor his work.